# defun and lambda in lisp

Tags: lambda, lisp

We have two ways to define a function: defun and lambda, and we can use setf for labeling a lambda function.

```
(defun g (x) (* x x)) 
(setf f (lambda (x) (+ x x)))
```

The function can be the first element in a list.

```
(g 3)
9
```

Or it can be a parameter to the other function.

```
(mapcar #'g '(1 2 3))
(1 4 9)
```

However with lambda, the usage is different.

```
(funcall f 3)
6

(mapcar f '(1 2 3))
(2 4 6)
```

I'm curious what's the logic behind the differences?

It's even more confusing compared with scheme's rather consistent use cases.

```
> (define (g x) (+ x x))
> (g 3)
6
> (map g '(1 3 4))
(2 6 8)

> (define f (lambda (x) (* x x)))
> (f 2)
4
> (map f '(1 2 3))
(1 4 9)
```

Comment: 2 namespaces, one for var's like f and one for functions like g. you'd have to `funcall` `g` once it's been passed into map

Comment: Yes, Scheme is consistent in this case.

Comment: GoZoner: to claim thnat Scheme is consistent is religion, because it implies that anything else is inconsistent. Lisp is consistent in separating function and value namespaces, which extends in a consistent way to further namespaces. For instance, the existence of a `(defclass foo ..)` does not prevent you from having a function called `foo` or a lexical or dynamic variable called `foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Kent Pitman's paper [Technical Issues of Separation in Function Cells and Value Cells](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Technical-Issues.html)